# How to remove all css classes and js in material design, to get default select box

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, materialize

I want to remove all css classes and js in material design, and make a select box look like basic html.

I want this:

[image]

To be this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you have tagged your question [materializecss](/questions/tagged/materializecss), per the documentation at http://materializecss.com/forms.html, you need to add the class `browser-default` to your `<select>` thus

```
 <label>Browser Select</label>
  <select class="browser-default">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks, so I'm **not** offering my hack https://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/mw3c38co/ :-) I really should start learning materializecss.